# create relative links with Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have the following code which loops through a list of countries and creates a href links

```
<div class="container" th:each="country: ${countryList}">
    <a th:href="${country.countryAbbr}"><div clss="row" th:text="${country.country}"></div></a>
</div>
```

The current page url is "localhost:8080/directory", and the generated url is showing as

"localhost:8080/us"

How can I make the url show as "localhost:8080/directory/us"

I want "us" to be added to the current url of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try create the following code in your Controller class.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String rootGet() {
    return "redirect:/directory";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder`:

```
<div th:with="urlBuilder=${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder)}"
class="container" th:each="country: ${countryList}">
    <a th:href="${urlBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path(${country.countryAbbr}).toUriString()}">
      <div clss="row" th:text="${country.country}"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this one

```
<div class="container" th:each="country: ${countryList}">
    <a th:href="@{${country.countryAbbr}}"><div clss="row" th:text="${country.country}"></div></a>
</div>
```

Using `@` usually resolves the default context but I am not aware of your environment.

For example, if you had Tomcat `.war` file, and your application would be hosted at `localhost:8080/myApp`, you would want result `/myApp/us` rather then `/us`. `@` would do that trick.

### If above is not relevant for you, use this one:

```
<div class="container" th:each="country: ${countryList}">
    <a th:href="@{'/directory/' + ${country.countryAbbr}}"><div clss="row" th:text="${country.country}"></div></a>
</div>
```